# Вывести и сразу же внести данные в бд

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Есть рабочий код с регистрацией пользователя и кнопкой которая выводит рандомное изображение из бд.
Так вот вопрос, как я могу сделать что бы при нажатии кнопки вывода этого изображения на сайт, данные этой картинки (имя и id) записывались в таблицу к юзеру.
index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
   <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
       <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Login</button>

            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <form id="form" role="form">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div id="messages"></div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="login"
               id="login" placeholder="vvedi login">

                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <form id="box1" metod="post" class="small-form">


           <div><button class="btn btn-info" name="img">mint</button></div>
        </form>
        <form id="box2" metod="post" class="small-form">

                <div><button class="btn btn-info">mint</button></div>
             </form>
             <form id="box3" metod="post" class="small-form">

                     <div><button class="btn btn-info">mint</button></div>
                  </form>

        </div>
        <div class="text-center img-block" id="img" name="img" >

        </div>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         <script src="post-ajax.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('#form').submit(function(e) {

                var form = $(this);
                var formdata = false;
                if(window.FormData){
                    formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
                }

                var formAction = form.attr('action');

                $.ajax({
                    type        : 'POST',
                    url         : 'check.php',
                    cache       : false,
                    data        : formdata ? formdata : form.serialize(),
                    contentType : false,
                    processData : false,
                    dataType: 'json',

                    success: function(response) {

                        if(response.type == 'success') {
                            $('#messages').addClass('alert alert-success').text(response.message);
                        } else {
                            $('#messages').addClass('alert alert-danger').text(response.message);
                        }
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

check.php

```
<?php
$login = filter_var(trim($_POST['login']),
                    FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);



$mysql = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','register-bd');
$mysql->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`login` ,`coin`) VALUES('$login' , '$coin')");
$mysql->close();
header('Location: /');


?>
```

box1.php

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'register-bd');

// If the connection did not work, display an error message
if (!$connect)
{
    echo 'Error Code: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . '<br>';
    echo 'Error Message: ' . mysqli_connect_error() . '<br>';
    exit;
}

        // Create a query
        $query = 'SELECT id,name,filename
            FROM box1
            ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1';

        // Execute the query
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

        // If there is no result, display an error message
        if (!$result)
        {
            echo 'Error Message: ' . mysqli_error($connect) . '<br>';
            exit;
        }

        // Display the number of recirds found
        echo '<p>The query found ' . mysqli_num_rows($result) . ' rows:</p>';

        // Loop through the records found
        while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {

            // Output the record using if statements and echo
            echo '<hr>';

            echo '<div class= table name:img>'.$record['name'].'</div>';

            echo '<img src="'.$record['filename'].'" width="300">';

        }



        ?>
```

post-ajax.js

```
$("#box1").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.loader').show();
    $.post("box1.php", {
        typeImg: $('[name="typeImg"]:checked').val()
    })
    .done(function(result) {
        $('.img-block').html(result);
        img = $(".img-block img");
        if (img.length > 0) {
            img.one('load', function() {
                console.log('img load');
                $('.loader').hide();
            });
        } else $('.loader').hide();
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert('Ошибка!');
    });
});
```

добавил отдельный инсерт, от ошибки самого ajax избавился, но данные просто не заносятся в нужную таблицу, будто действие и не выпонялется

```
<?php
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'register-bd');


        $query =  ("SELECT *
            FROM `box1`
            ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");


        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

         $record = $result->fetch_assoc();


        {

            echo '<hr>';

            echo '<div class= table name:img>'.$record['id'].'</div>';

            echo '<img src="'.$record['filename'].'" width="300">';

        }
        ?>
    <?php
    $img = $record['id'];
    $user = $_COOKIE['user'];
    echo $user, $img;

    $query =  ("INSERT INTO `inv` (`login`, `name`) VALUES ('$user', '$img')");

        ?>
```

Comment: Ну так в код получения картинки из БД, добавьте код записи информации в БД. В чём конкретно проблема?

Comment: в том что видимо ajax начинает как то конфликтовать при этом действие  и выдается ошибка вместо желаемого

Comment: $mysql->query("INSERT INTO `inv` (`img`) VALUES('$name')"); я понимаю что нужно добавить вот эту строчку в новую таблицу, где к авторизованному юзеру прикрепится name картинки, но что то не работает

Comment: тяжело без кода понять где и чего вы добавили. А уж без текста ошибки понять почему не работает совершенно невозможно

Comment: дополнил что сделал в коде

Comment: $query = mysqli_query когда добавляю идентификатор выходит как раз та самая .fail(function() {
        alert('Ошибка!'); из ajax

Comment: А посмотреть в логах причину ошибки не нужно? А как ваш  `$query =  ("INSERT INTO ...` должен работать. Вот вы объявили строку и думаете, что строка сама пойдёт в БД?